# Прервать функцию с горутинами , если выполняется слишком долго

Tags: golang

Задача, в функции нужно запустить несколько горутин с вычислениями и дождаться их окончания, но если функция будет работать больше указанного количества секунд прервать ее выполнение

минимальный пример

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
"sync"
)

func FibonacciRecursion(n int) int {
    if n <= 1 {
        return n
    }
    return FibonacciRecursion(n-1) + FibonacciRecursion(n-2)
}

func f(i int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    fmt.Println(FibonacciRecursion(45 + i))
}

func fun() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        go f(i, &wg)
       wg.Add(1)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    println("Function ended")
}

func main() {
    fun()
}
```

Надо прервать выполнение функции fun, как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, для таких целей используется пакет [context](https://pkg.go.dev/context)

Вот тут подробно на русском [Разбираемся с пакетом Context в Golang](https://habr.com/ru/company/nixys/blog/461723/)

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    timeLimit := time.Second * 10
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), timeLimit)
    defer cancel()
    fun(ctx)
}

func isDone(ctx context.Context) bool {
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        return true
    default:
        return false
    }
}

func FibonacciRecursion(ctx context.Context, n int) int {
    if n <= 1 || isDone(ctx) {
        return n
    }
    return FibonacciRecursion(ctx, n-1) + FibonacciRecursion(ctx, n-2)
}

func f(ctx context.Context, i int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    fmt.Println(FibonacciRecursion(ctx, 45+i))
}

func fun(ctx context.Context) {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go f(ctx, i, &wg)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    println("Function ended")
}
```